# How to upgrade to 3.2.1.0 in Mono

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, npgsql

Npgsql 3.1.9 is used in ASP.NET MVC4 application in Mono 4.4.1

Visual Studio Community Edition 2015 is used for develpment.

Ngpsql was upgraded to 3.2.1.0 from Nuget package manager.

It installed a lot of new .NET framework assemblies.

Application was re-compiled in Visual Studio and copied to Debian Linux into Mono.

Trying to run application in Mono now causes exception

```
Could not load type 'System.Net.HttpStatusDescription' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
```

with stack trace below.

How to run this application in Mono using latest npgsql?
In windows from Visual Studio it runs OK.

```
Could not load type 'System.Net.HttpStatusDescription' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Net.HttpStatusDescription' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
  at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+<CopyResponseStatusAndHeadersAsync>d__31.MoveNext () <0x40bbf6b0 + 0x000eb> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x40bc12f0 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x40bc0e60 + 0x0010b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x40bc0cb0 + 0x000b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x413bc1b0 + 0x00042> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () <0x414e3410 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+<CopyResponseAsync>d__7.MoveNext () <0x40bbebc0 + 0x002b5> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x40bc12f0 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x40bc0e60 + 0x0010b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x40bc0cb0 + 0x000b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x413bc1b0 + 0x00042> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x414bdce0 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+<ProcessRequestAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext () <0x40b80500 + 0x006e9> in <filename unknown>:0 
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
  at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () <0x40bc12f0 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x40bc0e60 + 0x0010b> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x40bc0cb0 + 0x000b3> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) <0x413bc1b0 + 0x00042> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () <0x414bdce0 + 0x0001a> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.TaskAsyncResult.Wait (IAsyncResult result) <0x40bc1ce0 + 0x000c9> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpTaskAsyncHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest (IAsyncResult result) <0x40bc1cb0 + 0x00013> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplication.async_handler_complete_cb (IAsyncResult ar) <0x4158bc70 + 0x000ee> in <filename unknown>:0
```

**Update**

I uninstalled Netstandard.library package with dependencies using forced uninstall in nuget.
Added  System.Net.Http.dll assemby to refences from .NET 4.6 framework assemblies with Copy Local true.
Removed and installed again Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core package

Now running in mono causes error

```
System.InvalidProgramException
Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue:.ctor (string): method body is empty.

Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or object): System.Net.Http.Formatting.
Exception stack trace:
  at System.Net.Http.Formatting.MediaTypeConstants..cctor () <0x41e7fb00 + 0x00033> in <filename unknown>:0 
Version Information: 4.4.1 (Nightly 4.4.1.0/4747417 K juuli 20 01:02:20 EEST 2016); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.42000
```

I tried also to install System.Net.Http.dll nuget package but in this case exception described in start of this question occurs in Mono.

Comment: Can you please test with the latest version of mono (4.8) and confirm whether that works better?

Comment: Mono is used in lot of production sites. Upgrading requires recompiling in a number of production sites: lot of work and testing. I downgraded back to 3.1.9 but problem persists. Maybe 3.2.1.0 installs come assemblies which cause this. `System.Net.HttpStatusDescription` does not exist in .NET 4.6 so it should not referenced. It was added to System.Net.Http.dll after .NET 4.6

Comment: Installing more recent versions of mono doesn't require compiling from source - you can follow instructions at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/linux/

Comment: Old Debian squeeze is used in main server. For this compiling from source is required. It is doable, if new mono works on squeeze

Comment: OK. It doesn't really make sense for the error to persist after downgrading, I'd make sure you cleaned everything, re-restored packages etc.

Comment: Note that I'm looking into removing the .NET Standard dependencies which have been introduced to Npgsql 3.2.

Comment: Downgrade only replaces npgsql, other packages remained installed. Only restoring solution from backup helps. I can wait for new release. Or maybe it is resonable to add npgsql project to my solution and change it so that it does not need .NET standard. Upgrading Mono on single server is reasonable, unfortunately I have lot of different production servers which all needs to be upgraded if new mono works.

Comment: Am not sure how you're installing things, but you should be able to remove the dependencies that were brought in by Npgsql 3.2.

Comment: Should I uninstall additional packages installed by npgsql 3.2 after it is installed from nuget package manager

Comment: Sure, ideally just roll back your packages.config and csproj with got or whatever

Comment: I tried but got `Invalid IL code in System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue` in Mono. I updated question. Maybe I should wait for new version of npgsql or try to add npgsql project to my solution and try to remove additional references. Not sure will in work with .NET 4.6 System.Net.Http.dll or requires newer from nuget package through some indirect dependeny. npgsql does not use http protocol so I hope it should work with any of this assembly version

Comment: You should seriously consider moving to .NET Core.

Comment: Does .NET Core require newer Mono ?